# How to correctly handle WS_EX_COMPOSITED?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi, doublebuffered

Someone can explain how to create WndProc that is handling bug caused by WS_EX_COMPOSITED (the bug is endless WM_PAINT on some controls) ?

All what i use for WS_EX_COMPOSITED is when my app window is hidden to be able to take screenshot of it(if WS_EX_COMPOSITED not set, PrintWindow fails), i get screenshot but the CPU usage is 99% always.

Here is information i found from google:
[Never ending WM_PAINT loop with ATL CWindowImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117511/never-ending-wm-paint-loop-with-atl-cwindowimpl)
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=483719

But doesnt give me very brightness... the only change i added to my WndProc is the following:

```
if(Msg==WM_PAINT||Msg==WM_NCPAINT||Msg==WM_ERASEBKGND) { return DefWindowProc(hWnd,Msg,wParam,lParam); }
```

It lowers the CPU usage but its not painting all controls correctly.